# Lilypond - apply a repeating rhythmic pattern to all notes

Tags: lilypond

Assuming I have a pattern like this:

```
\relative c' {
  c4 d e f8 g
  d4 e f g8 a
  e4 f g a8 b
  f4 g a b8 c
}
```

How can a define the rhythmic pattern to be applied to all notes so I only had to input the note durations one time?

```
% I imagine it to look somehow like this:

definerhytmicpattern = {
  4 4 4 8 8
}

\relative c' {
  c d e f g
  d e f g a
  e f g a b
  f g a b c
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not leave it and [I found this](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=654) on the [Lilypond Snippet Repository](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Search).

Download the newest file with `wget`:

```
wget http://gillesth.free.fr/Lilypond/changePitch/changePitch.ly
```

then:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\include "changePitch.ly"

pattern = { c4 c4 c4 c8 c8 }
newnotes = \relative c' {
  c d e f g
  d e f g a
  e f g a b
  f g a b c
}

\score {
  \changePitch \pattern \newnotes
}
```

outputs:

[image]

you can also add articulation:

```
[...]
pattern = { c4-> c4-. c4-. c8( c8) }
[...]
```

[image]

and dynamics:

```
[...]
pattern = { c4-\p c4\< c4 c8( c8)-\! }
[...]
```

[image]

...and even fingerings! (just awesome)

```
[...]    
pattern = { c4-1 c4-2 c-3 c8(-4 c8)-5 }
[...]
```

[image]

detailed documentation for this function can be found here: [PDF](http://gillesth.free.fr/Lilypond/changePitch/changePitch-doc.pdf)